# Know users logged in culture per user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the best place to know the `CurrentCulture` for each user logged in and do some setting per user based on that culture?

Can I use static constructor to assign static property!

Can I do something like this!!

```
 public class MetricSystemHelper
{
    private static bool _isMetric;
    static MetricSystemHelper()
    {
        RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);

        if (true == region.IsMetric)
        {
            _isMetric = true;
        }
        else //  USA, Liberia, Myanmar(Only these countries doesn't use metric)
        {
            _isMetric = false;
        };
    }


    public static bool IsMetric
    {
        get
        {
             return _isMetric;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` property to retrieve the culture info of the current ASP.NET user. If you need to persist this information you could store it in the database when the user logs in. But you should be aware that inside an ASP.NET application this property is populated from the [`<globalization>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element in your web.config file.

So for example:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
```

`auto` are the default values. ASP.NET will then use the `Accept-Language` HTTP request header to populate this property. This property is usually sent by the client browser on each request. But be careful of the following gotcha: the same user could have 2 browsers (say Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox) and he could have configured different culture settings in those browsers. So when he visits your website you could get different results for the same user.

If on the other hand you want to manage Language or Culture preference for the user in a browser agnostic way you should provide the user with the possibility to tell you his preference. For example this could be a setting in your website that the user could modify and you would store in the database.

Comment: That's a lot easier than what I was going to propose. I thought you had to read off the `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: Hi Darin, I don't want to store the information in Database, though want to use this in many views.So what I mean is set it once per ASP.Net user and use it in different views.

Comment: @YogendraSingh, keeping in mind what Darin said, you can likely just store this in the session.

Comment: If you decide to use the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` property you don't need to be storing it in a database. You could simply set a property on your view model to it and you will have it accessible everywhere and on all views.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov , I have different View Model for each view, and I don't want to set this property for each view model.Instead what I want is to set it in one class as a property and use it in all the other view model.SO for this case what is the best way to do!

Comment: You could use a child action then: `Html.Action`. The child action will have a completely separate lifecycle from the main action. You could have a separate view model for it. And then for example render it on your Layout so that it appears on all views. Or alternatively you could write a custom HTML helper that will read the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` property and render some HTML. As you can see there really are lots of ways to achieve this in ASP.NET MVC. Just pick one that suits to your needs. Then try to implement it.